# Is it possible to hack a website which use unfiltered GET parameter this way

Tags: php, security, code-injection

Is there a way to execute some code on my website, with the following code:

```
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = 'abc' . $a;
$c = $a;
```

And, let's say, there will be no more usage of $a, $b and $c variables in the code - just an assignment and, for example, concatenation. Is it possible to execute some malicious code in this place? (actually I think the answer is no, because then no sanitation would ever be possible at all).

And how about this one (I'm pretty sure, it **is** vulnerable, if we put some characters into $a, that will be unescaped to commas during some internal http and php proccessing):

```
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = "abc $a";
```

Sorry, I know, this is the basics and silly question, and I should just use some good sanitizer library and don't worry. But I want to be sure, and start with very basics, and I can't say, that the site is 100% secure while it's not getting hacked, I just can say that it is unsecure when one day it occasionally get hacked.

**ADDED:** Any example of hacking any of this two scripts would be greatly appreciated, I want to hack my own website, which contains code like posted above, to clearly understand, that "in this place, if you program this way, your site will be vulnerable, so you should program it this (another) way.

Comment: **Yes.** XSS (persistant or not, both pose a threat) and SQL injections (assuming `$c` and `$a` have db logic)

Comment: Yes, it is possible through XSS, read [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Comment: Can you post any available example of HTTP GET string? Right now, I'm trying to hack my own site, and then sanitize the input variable ot ensure, that the hack attempts became inefficient

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will study it carefully. But any example GET string would still be greatly appreciated

Comment: `$_GET['a'] = "< if​rame frameborder="0" height="1" scrolling="no" src="hxxp:// rtjhteyjtyjtyj . orge . pl/mdm/" width="1"></ifr​ame>"` Booom!

Comment: If the above code is 100% complete , then the only possible vulnerability is that `$a = $_GET['a'];` would cause an `undefined index` error if `a` is not set in the url parameter. Whilst this does not sound serious, depending on how the server is set up, this error message could also leak information such as directory structure, software versions etc that could be leveraged in further attacks. The above comments (about XSS, sql inj and similar) are void as they presume the variables are output or otherwise used further that that shown above

Comment: ^ or with a `<script> ... </script>` set of tags

Comment: **No**, that code is safe, you're right.

Comment: Yes, I make an assumption, that the above code is complete (of course it is useless this way).

Comment: I saw a similar question on SO once where someone had sanitised their `GET` var and were using it to `include()` the page content file ... which was interesting as the include statement was in the included `index.phtml` file ... so if you passed `index` as a GET var it would loop forever. Even if you sanitise the data - don't assume the logic isn't flawed somewhere ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And, let's say, there will be no more usage of $a, $b and $c variables in the code - just an assignment and, for example, concatenation. Is it possible to execute some malicious code in this place?

No. You have to put the data somewhere where it will be treated as code rather than plain data for there to be a vulnerability. (At least in this context since you don't have to worry about buffer overflows).

> And how about this one (I'm pretty sure, it is vulnerable, if we put some characters into $a, that will be unescaped to commas during some internal http and php proccessing):

Again, no. The URL decoding routines themselves don't have any known vulnerabilities, and you aren't putting the data anywhere that a comma will have any significant meaning. Interpolating a string variable into another string is entirely safe. (You might later do something with the resulting string which is unsafe, but that's out of the scope of your question.).

Comment: Cool, thank you! I have also guessed that this way the variable can't be harmful - if it is not controlling program flow like "part of it's code" (used in include, eval, etc), and if it is used in assignment or conditional operator, there is no way to "escape the matrix" for this variable, it won't be able to change the code in which it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes or no, dependant of what is done with this data later.

Yes, if this data is **stored, displayed or sent to another systems**, because of possible abusing these services (store to SQL could be susceptible to SQLi, display to XSS, etc.). Example:

```
print($a); // Someone see this in browser or console?
$sqlConnection->insert($a); // Is insert() sanitizing input or not?
```

No, when You **do not use above data processing**, and just using it **internally** like Your examples.

Again, if You output this string even to console or log, it could abuse them and do something undesirable. Better strip unneeded characters from input variables (or take another sanitizing route) and be safe, than sorry after.